# Compare a list of values on one tab to values in columns in 3 other tabs and return the value matched plus a corresponding value in the next column

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure if this is possible using regular excel functions or if i would have to venture into the VBA world to make this work.
I have sheet1 that has a list of values, I want to be able to compare all these values to columns D,K & O in sheet2, 3 & 4. If there is a match with any of these values I would like it to return a copy of the matched value on sheet 4 (as many times as needed in rows) along with the values corresponding number in a column next to it. I hope I am making somewhat sense, if not, let me know and Ill try to explain better.
Thanks in advanced for your assistance.

I have tried to research but can't find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.